# Domains where every polynomial splits

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A$ is an integral domain and every non-constant $f(x)\in A[x]$ splits into linear factors, is $A$ necessarily a field? I'm not sure whether or not this should be true.

If $A$ is finite, then this is trivially true as every finite domain is a field. If $A$ isn't finite and $\operatorname{char} A\neq 2$, then it at least has infinitely many units. To see why, suppose otherwise and let $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ be all the units. Since $A$ is a domain, $\pm 1$ are the only units that are their own inverse. Therefore, $u_1\cdots u_n = -1$ and thus
$$(x-u_1)\cdots(x-u_n) = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x - 1$$
for some $a_i\in A$. Therefore, as each $(x-u_i)$ doesn't divide $2$ (which is nonzero as $\operatorname{char} A\neq 2$) we have that $(x-u_i)$ doesn't divide

$$(x-u_1)\cdots(x-u_n) + 2 =  a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + 1.$$

Since $n$ is at least two (as $\pm 1$ are distinct units since $\operatorname{char} A\neq 2$), we can write
$$a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + 1 = (x-v_1)\cdots(x-v_n)$$
for some $v_1,\ldots, v_n \in A - \{u_1,\ldots, u_n\}$.
Since $v_1\cdots v_n = 1$, each of the $v_i$ is a unit. This contradicts the fact that the $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ were all the units, and thus $A$ has infinitely many units.

I don't think this argument can be extended to show that every nonzero element of $A$ is a unit, though.

Answer (score 4):

In the ring of algebraic integers (not a field), every nonconstant polynomial factors into linear terms. This is a consequence of Gauss's Lemma for number fields. See for example Corollary 8.8 in my [paper with David McKinnon.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037491)

From Theorem 9.13 you can also see that the property holds if and only if $A$ is a Schreier domain whose field of fractions is algebraically closed.

Comment: Any way to see the paper without library access?

Comment: @OlderAmateur Here's a link from Arturo's coauthor's website: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~dmckinno/Papers/Gauss.pdf

Comment: @mattematician Thanks.